# What Language/Framework To Use For This Interactive Website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a website which provides news stories in the form of cell bubbles. As news stories become more popular, the bubbles rise from the bottom towards the top of the webpage. Please see this link for a rough prototype: https://www.fluidui.com/editor/live/preview/p_yPy7q7EccTK7TE1Xhb9MRlVtp54v24E5.1374716630665

I was wondering what front-end language(s)/framework(s) I should use to accomplish this. The bubble text and position will be updated in real-time from a server. I want these bubbles to have fluid animations when they shrink, expand, and even "bump" into each other.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use, of course, HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Optionally, you can use a JavaScript library (like jQuery) to make things easier.

And then you need a server language. There are lots of them, such as PHP or node.js

Probably, you will also need a database, like SQLite or MySQL.

To sum up, you have lots of possibilities because you can do the same thing with different languages. Then, you should choose the language that appeals most to you, or that you know more.